# How to match information from different methods in c#

Tags: c#, methods, matching

I am in the midst of writing a program that will take information from methods that I have created and then writes an email to the user the data they've gathered. The data that they gather are error messages on clients trying to get into a mobile app by either trying to logging in or register. Below is what I am trying to say in the main method of my program:

```
foreach(Transaction event in recentFailedTransactions)
{
  if(!TransactionSuccessFound(transaction))
    {
       //Match the response data from TransactionFailure with information from myhome.ToString();
    }
```

So my main question is: from the two methods that I develop, is there a feature in .NET that will let me combine these two methods so I can get the data into a string? Or am I going to have to re-develop my methods? Below are the methods I am receiving data from. The failure method gathers all the data that are errors, and the myhome method gathers all the userinformation required. Any help is appreciated!

```
//failure method
private static List<TransactionInformation> TransactionFailures(DateTime lastRanTime)
    {
  List<TransactionInformation> recentFailedTransactions = new List<TransactionInformation>();
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MOBILEConnectionString))
    {
    SqlCommand sqlError = connection.CreateCommand();
    sqlError.CommandText = @"SELECT SERVICE_ID, REQUEST_DATA, RESPONSE_DATA, DATE_ENTERED FROM WS_TRANSACTION WHERE SERVICE_ID IN ('GetUserTokenLogin', 'RegisterUser') AND RESPONSE_DATA LIKE '%false%' ORDER BY DATE_ENTERED DESC";
    connection.Open();  
    SqlDataReader reader = sqlError.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
      {
       List<string> transactionElementList = new List<string>();
       transactionElementList.Add(reader.GetString(0));

       foreach (string line in transactionElementList)
       {
         TransactionInformation fail = new TransactionInformation();
         fail.ServiceID = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["SERVICE_ID"]);
         fail.RequestData = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["REQUEST_DATA"]);
         fail.ResponseData = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["RESPONSE_DATA"]);
         fail.TransactionDate = Utilities.FromDBValue<DateTime>(reader["DATE_ENTERED"]);
         string[] exception = fail.ResponseData.Split(new[] { '{', '"', ':', '}' }).Skip(1).ToArray();
         fail.DisplayException = exception[0 + 1];
         fail.InternalException = exception[2 + 3];


          switch (Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["SERVICE_ID"]))
           {
           case "GetUserTokenLogin":
           string[] login = line.Split(new[] { '[', '|', ']' }).Skip(1).ToArray();

            fail.Type = TransactionInformation.TransactionType.Login;
            fail.UserName = login[0];
            break;
            case "RegisterUser":
            string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { '[', ']' }).Skip(1).ToArray();

            fail.Type = TransactionInformation.TransactionType.Registration;
            fail.UserName = parts[0];
            fail.Email = parts[1];
            fail.FirstName = parts[2];
            fail.LastName = parts[3];
            fail.PNRLocator = parts[4];
            break;
            default:
            throw new Exception("Unknown service id");
           }
          recentFailedTransactions.Add(fail);
        }

       }
     }
    return recentFailedTransactions;
  }

      //MyHome method
      private static List<MyHome> GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
    {
        List<MyHome> myHomeInformation = new List<MyHome>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyHomeConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlError = connection.CreateCommand();
            sqlError.CommandText = @"SELECT USER_NAME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TRAVELER_UID FROM TANDT_PORTAL.dbo.[USER]";
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlError.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MyHome userInformation = new MyHome();
                foreach (MyHome item in myHomeInformation)
                {
                    userInformation.myHomeUserName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["USER_NAME"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeEmail = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["EMAIL"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeFirstName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["FIRST_NAME"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeLastName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["LAST_NAME"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeTravelerUID = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["TRAVELER_UID"]);
                    myHomeInformation.Add(userInformation);
                }
            }
        }
        return myHomeInformation;
    }
```

Comment: So basically, you want 2 outputs in your method? You can use a parameter with the out keyword in that case.

Comment: @kailanjian kinda. I want to be able to match the data from the failure method with the myhome method so that I can create a string to use as an email body.

Comment: How about a LINQ join? Have you considered that?

Comment: Can you join by LINQ? I thought joining only worked for SQL?

Comment: Yes, you can, if that is what you need, I can come up with a sample for you.

Comment: That would be awesome if you could provide a sample @kailanjian. I have never seen it done before in LINQ so it will be interesting to see how it is accomplished

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but I hope you can make use of this. This matches together `MyClass` and `TransactionInformation` object if they have the same username and makes a list of anonymous type that contains the matching objects. Check it out:

```
    private static void JoinSample()
    {
        List<TransactionInformation> failures = ...
        List<MyHome> myHomeData = ...

        var joined =
            from f in failures // Iterate failures
            join d in myHomeData on // Join with myHomeData
            f.Username equals d.MyHomeUserName // when the username matches
            select new // store values in anonymous type
            {
                MyHome = d,
                Failure = f
            };

        foreach (var item in joined)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.MyHome.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(item.Failure.ToString());
        }
    }
```